# Why are images overextending themselves for hover in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am attempting to make an interactive map in HTML/CSS but I'm having issues with the hover function clipping images that the cursor is not hovered over.

For example, hovering my mouse at the yellow spot will trigger the hover of Oregon:
http://prntscr.com/rkv3on
This is the similar case for Washington: http://prntscr.com/rkv4cf

HTML code:

```
<div align="left">
    <div>
        <div class="ORcontainer">
            <img src="GShomepageUSMAPnavyOR.png" alt="img" class="ORimage">
            <div class="ORoverlay ORoverlayFade">
                <img src="GShomepageUSMAPgreyor.png" alt="OR" class="ORimage">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.ORcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px;
    left: 228px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ORimage {
    display: block;
    width: 194px;
    height: 150px;
}
.ORoverlayFade{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.ORoverlay {position: absolute; opacity: 0; transition:all .3s ease;}
.ORcontainer:hover .ORoverlay,.ORcontainer:hover .ORoverlayFade {opacity: 1;}
```

I am assuming it is with the photos themselves but they are png's and do not extend past the borders of the states themselves.

FYI: This is one of my first experiences with HTML/CSS so this is probably the wrong way about going about this project and there is probably a simple solution I'm not seeing. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - I am noticing in your image tags `<img` that you are not specifying height and width - is that by design?

Comment: Screenshot links not working.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui This one should work. https://imgur.com/a/pjwEMyd

Comment: @Nelles All the individual images were made from one large map so I didn't want to alter any of the heights and widths unproportionally. I can change them to the same as those in the CSS code if you think it will have an effect.

Comment: It's would very helpful if you create any codepen or stackbliz, to understand your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent of the image class to `position: relative;`,  `position: absolute;` will not bound the image to the box. I would also use flexbox in the parent container as it does a great job of centering images in containers.

```
.ORcontainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 108px;
    left: 228px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    &  img {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
        &:after {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```